# python - convert curl command

Tags: python, curl

I have this curl command.

This works

```
curl -O -H "X-Api:3433432" -X GET "https://website.com/file.zip"
```

Trying to figure it out how to convert it to something python understands.

```
curl -O -H "X-Api:3433432" -X GET "https://website/file.zip"
```

Comment: What do you mean by python understands?

Comment: What filename are you trying to export to?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for the "Requests" module?
It allows you to create a GET request in a similar way you would use a `curl` command.

You can find some documentation at:
https://www.w3schools.com/PYTHON/ref_requests_get.asp

Edit: There's also https://curlconverter.com/ which should convert it automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

try using module `requests`:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'X-Api': '3433432',
}

response = requests.get('https://website.com/file.zip', headers=headers)
```